# Can we insert into a table if a tablock is applied by some other query on the table already in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert some records in a table using `insert into...select` statement (with `TABLOCK`). But I am not able to do so.

Thing is that some other query is already applied `TABLOCK` on the table. Is this the reason?

When I am trying to insert without tablock, it is getting inserted.

Truncate and Drop statement are also not working.

Answer (score 0):

`WITH (TABLOCK)` changes the behaviour of SQL Server's locking - instead of locking just the affected rows, it locks **the entire table**.

So if you have an `INSERT` operation going, it will place an **exclusive, table-wide** lock - no other operations can now access that table in any way, until that first transaction holding the lock is finished.

Without the `(TABLOCK)` hint, SQL Server only places exclusive locks on those rows being inserted - any other rows are still accessible (and can even be updated or deleted).

`WITH (TABLOCK)` is a big heavy sledgehammer - **use it WITH CAUTION!**